# Changing the keyboard layout to nordic?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am a fairly new user of Emacs, which I could be my offline installation of LaTeX instead of using Overleaf. I wanted the same keyboard layout that I use on that site, which is the same as my Mac keyboard. I can't use backslash `\` for writing `\begin`... and use the `{}`, so it is quite hard to write LaTeX inside Emacs. All I have installed is default emacs, AUCTex and evil. I haven't configured anything despite that.
I've tried to search all over Google and finding answers, inserting them into my config, but nothing really works?

I normally use `SHIFT+OPTION7` to do a backslash and `SHIFT+OPTION+8` or `SHIFT+OPTION+9` to do `{` and `}`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this set of config lines in my `.emacs` fixed it

```
(setq mac-option-key-is-meta nil)
(setq mac-command-key-is-meta t)
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-option-modifier nil)
```

I'm not a lisp expert and I don't remember wher I found those in the first place :-)
I have a Norwegian keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to improve this question before it can be answered. For one thing, if you normally use `Command-Shift-7` to type a backslash, and that isn’t working inside Emacs, what does Emacs do instead? Also, if you type `C-h k Command-Shift-7`, what does Emacs say that this key combination does?

Generally keyboard layouts are handled by the operating system, and Emacs doesn’t need to get involved.

Comment: I tried to do a backslash, it first tells there is no dynamic expression for 'produced. When I try do to the C-h k SHIFT+OPTION+7 it tells me its reserved for M-/ for something called dabbrev-expand ARG.

Comment: A comment maybe, but certainly not an answer (particularly given the well-stated objection in your first sentence).

Comment: ok, so Emacs understood `SHIFT-OPTION-7` as `M-/`, which is interesting. I suppose that `SHIFT-7` gives a forward slash and the option key is supposed to make it give a backslash? You might try typing `C-u C-\` to switch input methods, and choosing the Danish one.

Comment: Nick, you are of course correct. The same thought occurred to me right after I had submitted it.

Comment: @db48x Shift+7 actually does a '-' so no forward slash. Shift+command+7 gives a forward slash. I tried to do `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
  (lambda () (set-input-method "danish-prefix")))` as well, but it is still the same.

Comment: I think I solved the problem by using this in the config file
`(when (eq system-type 'darwin)
  (setq mac-option-modifier 'none))` not sure what it precisely does, but it lets me use my normal keys.

Comment: You should write this comment as an answer (and you can accept it as well after a couple of days).